# Why does CSS use colons ":" in rules?

Tags: css, syntax, language-design

CSS properties use no spaces so why isn't the first space in the rule used as a separator between the property and the value?

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: why don't you think the second solution is "cleaner"? I prefer the first one, it is easier to read, don't you think?

Comment: I'd guess it's something to do with the generic "key":"value" syntax used by most other scripting languages ;-) Why change something that works really well anyway?

Comment: The second one is definitely not cleaner.

Comment: I get why people disagree, but should this question really be downvoted? It's not unclear or unuseful, even if it's slightly obnoxious it's a valid question right?

Comment: One could equally well say that you don't need the assignment operator in most languages. Instead of having "foo = 123, fum = 456" you could write "foo 123, fum 456"!

Comment: Seems like more of a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Emanuil anyone could say that :) the point being though that the discussion is not at all limited to CSS and colons, but rather to syntax in general. What syntax makes a program clearer and easier to understand and what adds nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not remove the curly-braces as well and let indentation dictate the structure? That would be even cleaner.

However, sometimes better syntax is not about removing everything you can imagine, you often need to keep something to keep the syntax *clear* as well. A syntax that is more clear expresses the intention in a better way than a cleaner, more implicit syntax. It's harder to make mistakes with an explicit syntax, and easier to spot those mistakes.

In your two examples, I find the first one a lot easier to understand, because the key and the value are clearly, explicitly separated.

Comment: Personally, I'd like a no curly braces syntax better. I get your point though.

Comment: Isn't space the original separator? I mean the only reason the space character exists is to separate other characters. The readability is easily fixed with a proper syntax highlighter and the benefits of "no colon" are substantial - lighter files and easier to write.

Comment: Actually, the curly braces (and semicolons, and no single-line comments (`//`)) were all added to the standard to be able to completely strip all whitespace to reduce filesize. CSS is therefore pretty easy to minify. That might also be why there's a semicolon, to make it easier for software to read.

Comment: Cthulhu is completely right. Stripping out the whitespace is a common size optimization for CSS files. I'm not sure what you mean by "lighter files" if not their size, and semicolons definitely don't add more size to a file than you can remove by stripping out all the whitespace. If you're looking for a language based solely on whitespace, well, [we have just the thing for you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)). Perfectly light and "airy".

Comment: Except that in css you can't just strip away the whitespace between colon and semi-colon because CSS properties can be combined. `font: bold 12px/16px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;` has two spaces that can't be stripped.

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure whether a better answer can be given than "probably to avoid confusion".

Many elements in programming and markup languages are not 100% efficient in favour of improved readability. I personally find

```
background: red 1px url(images/test.jpg)
```

much, much clearer than

```
background red 1px url(images/test.jpg);
```

Comment: As does StackOverflow which has add syntax highlighting to the first example, not the second ;-)

Comment: @Alex: which, in reality, was the real reason the CSS spec team decided to use `:`. Praised be their precognitive senses!

Comment: It now does add some kind of syntax highlighting. Perhaps disable it?

Answer (score 10):

An accidental space is easier to put in and harder to spot than a missing colon.

Comment: Not if you have syntax highlighting. No colons would make CSS files lighter and faster to write.

Comment: @Emanuil: If you have a decent code editor with syntax highlighting, colons should be no problem, either. Write an extension to automatically insert them if it bothers you so much.

Comment: @Emanuil: Even with syntax highlighting, it's still harder to spot a missing space than a missing colon. No space wouldn't make a CSS file "lighter" because you're only dropping a whole one character per property - even with a massive stylesheet, you're still talking about a negligible improvement. Speed of pressing a space versus colon+space is also a negligible improvement. [Look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/LHdDy/). My eyes zip to the colons to see the value of each property, whereas with the spaces, there are other irrelevant spaces which confuse me.

Comment: @thirtydot, The property is blue and the value is red. How is it hard to distinguish them? I understand that the improvements in terms of space and speed of writing of the new syntax are not big, but I wouldn't say they are negligible.

Comment: @Emanuil: `"Negligible refers to the quantities so small that they can be ignored (neglected) when studying the larger effect."` - I'd say the *improvements* are definitely negligible, whereas the downsides are (to everyone who posted so far in this question) *detrimental*.

Answer (score 5):

It's just easier to use. It's more semantic and it's future proof if they change the rules at a later date.  It also makes debugging easier.

It's just an instance of usability over efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

As others stated, it is needed to give a clear syntax, which is flexible enough to choose your style (write rules in one line? write one key:value per line? etc.).

Let me give you an example. You could write this:

```
a {
  border: 1px
  solid black;
}
```

If you leave out all the syntax characters, this will become:

```
a {
  border 1px
  solid black
}
```

This is ambigous, or from the other point of view, the syntax is too rigid.

Comment: @vbence: I have not said it is nice :).

Comment: It is wouldn't be ambiguous if semi-colon was mandatory, like in C (I always put them, anyway). But good argument anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be willing to bet that most CSS parsers have some history of being written in C or C++ and the [strtok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Functions) function being used to parse the file, along similar rules for parsing a C/C++ file.

Others have already mentioned the ambiguity of using a white space separator.

The `;` is another important part of the syntax in both C and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Lot of languages use the `variableName: type` notation (declarations of variables, of parameters, etc.). I saw one using `variableName type` (perhaps it was [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29)) and I was disturbed by the look. Even if it is unambiguous, it "doesn't feel right", perhaps because of habits, perhaps because it is lacking "rhythm". Punctuation in an English sentence isn't always necessary (sometimes it is, to avoid ambiguity), but lacking it makes readers uncomfortable. The eye needs to find marks.

Idem for [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) (and its parent language), just omitting parentheses and commas for function parameters. It looks odd (but perhaps one can get addicted to this notation).

As always, there is a balance to strike, between too much annotations and too little. And between innovating and breaking habits... Innovation is nice, but it must have a purpose. Saving some keystrokes at the cost of readability is rarely a purpose. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by *"Idem for F#..."*? Is it *"It is an [idiom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiom#Noun) for F#..."*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I took your link, replaced idiom with [idem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idem), and bingo! you have your answer… Perhaps using "idem" for "same" is more French than English, but it seems still valid.